# Line Integral of a line segment

Tags: integration

Evaluate the line integral, where $C$ is the given curve.

$$\int_C xyz^2\, {\rm d}s,$$

$C$ is the line segment from $(-3,2,0)$ to $(-1,3,5)$.

I know how to set up the problem, but I keep getting an answer of 
$$-25\cdot 30^{1/2}\cdot \frac{17}{20},$$ which is not right.
You solve for the parametric equations, then integrate from $0$ to $1$.

$$x = -3+2t, y = 2+t, z = 5t$$

$$I =\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{30}(50t^4+25t^3-150t^2)dt =- \frac {135\sqrt{30} }{4}$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show your calculations?

Comment: I put them above ^

Comment: Your second answer is different from the first one.

Comment: I did it again and got a different answer. Am I correct?

Comment: The second answer is correct.

Comment: What makes you think you're wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Artem in the comment on the question, I've verified the second result in the question is the correct answer.